# Desktop Tower Wire solutions

Tags: case, tampering

I have a bunch of tower PCs I'm getting ready to put out, and I'm looking for something to make the wires coming out the back a little harder to tamper with and look a little nicer — something like a cheap wire cage that will be attached via the thumb screws.

I've been doing my own searching, but I can't find anything. It occurs to me that perhaps I just don't know the right keywords to use (which takes this beyond a shopping recommendation), and so I'm asking here if anyone can point me in the right direction.

I'm looking more here for aethetics — any tamper resistance is just a bonus.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for 'cable management'?

Comment: @Shinrai - not really, and solutions there tend to focus more on either server racks or internal cable arrangements anyway.

Comment: @Joel - Agreed that that is the usual concern, but it's really the same regardless of where it is.  I don't know of another name for it, and that's usually how I see velcro strapping, desk-attached cable brackets, etc sold.  (I am unfamiliar with a product like you're thinking about, that seems potentially problematic though.)

Comment: " wire cage that will be attached via the thumb screws."....Maybe you should invent one and make millions selling them, I have never seen these except for a few select models of Dells, nothing for the after market. Necessity if the mother of invention!

Comment: @Moab - haha, if only

Comment: By definition an entrepreneur is someone who see's what no one else does. Run with it man!

Answer (score 1):

Try a search on [`pc case "exterior cable management"`](http://www.google.com/search?q=pc+case+exterior+cable+management).

Some of the items on [this page](http://cableorganizer.com/desk-organizers/) look interesting and might be adaptable.

[image: WireMate™ Cord Organizer]

Here's a [case that includes integrated exterior cable management](http://www.bitfenix.com/global/en/products/chassis/colossus#overview).

[image: BitFenix Collosus]

[Here's a case](http://www.silverstonetek.com/products/p_contents.php?pno=FT02&area=usa) that has the motherboard rotated 90° so the cable attachment is at the top under a cover and they exit through an opening in the back.

[image][image][image]